# Invalid syntax on '=' when using global

Tags: python, syntax-error, global

```
f=1

def skip(i):
    global f +=i
    return
```

What's wrong?

I don't know

```
>>> f
1
>>> skip(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    skip(3)
  File "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/game.py", line 4, in skip
    f +=i
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'f' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: That code doesn't produce that error. I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at `+` in `global f +=i`.

Answer (score 9):

The `global` statement goes on a *separate* line:

```
def skip(i):
    global f
    f += i
```

The `return` is redundant here; I've left it off.

The [`global` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) 'marks' names in a function as global; it is a distinct statement and you can only give it one or more names (separated by commas):

```
global foo, bar, baz
```

It doesn't really matter where in the function you put them, as long as they are on a line of their own. The statement applies to the *whole* function. As such it makes sense to stick a `global` statement at the top, to avoid confusion.